# How to test if view controller is dismissed or popped

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

i want to write an unit test for my function, here is code:

```
  func smartBack(animated: Bool = true) {
    if isModal() {
      self.dismiss(animated: animated, completion: nil)
    } else {
      self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }
  }
```

This method automatically chooses dismiss or pop. So, how i can check if viewcontroller popped or dismissed after this function? Thank you for help

Comment: one solution is using events

Comment: u can check self.navigationController?.topViewController value

Comment: do you want to check inside the viewController ? if it was dismissed or poped ? or do you want to check on when did the viewController just removed

Comment: Instead of focusing on what method is called, test for the effect — is the view controller no longer displayed?

Comment: Btw, how is the function isModal() implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the view controller's `isBeingDismissed` property in either its `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` function.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2097562-isbeingdismissed.

Answer (score 1):

func smartBack(animated: Bool = true)  will be:

```
func smartBack(animated: Bool = true) {  
  if self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first == self {
                self.dismiss(animated: animated, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
}
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: I make an edit. Now my code is the answer to the first question "So, how I can check if view controller popped or dismissed": Answer is my func smartBack(animated: Bool = true):

Answer (score 1):

It is worked for me:

```
func smartBack(animated: Bool = true) {
            if self.navigationController == nil {
                self.dismiss(animated: animated, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use property **self.isBeingPresented**, will return true is view controller presented otherwise false if pushed.

Comment: This helps determine whether the view was pushed/presented. Not dismissed or popped.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the viewControllers stack and see if your viewController is included or not, using:

`self.navigationController.viewControllers`

This will return a `[UIViewController]` contained in the navigationController stack.

Comment: A presented view controller is not contained within the navigation stack

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use Mocks to track when certain methods are called.

You can do this like so:

```
class MockNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    var _popCalled: Bool = false
    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        _popCalled = true
        return self.viewControllers.first
    }
}
```

Then anytime your code calls popViewController, the `_popCalled` value would be updated but it wouldn't actually pop anything. So you can assert the `_popCalled` value to make sure that the expected call happened.

This makes it easy to test that an expected thing happened and also prevents you running actual code in your tests. This method could easily be a service call, or db update, setting a flag etc, so can be much safer.

They can be difficult to understand at first though. I would suggest reading up on them before heavy use.

**A full example in a playground:**

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import MapKit

class ClassUnderTest: UIViewController {
    var isModal: Bool = false

    func smartBack(animated: Bool = true) {
        if isModal {
            self.dismiss(animated: animated, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: animated)
        }
    }
}

class MockNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    var _popCalled: Bool = false
    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        _popCalled = true
        return self.viewControllers.first
    }
}

class MockClassUnderTest: ClassUnderTest {

    var _mockNavigationController = MockNavigationController()
    override var navigationController: UINavigationController? {
        return _mockNavigationController 
    }

    var _dismissCalled: Bool = false
    override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        _dismissCalled = true
    }

}

var subject = MockClassUnderTest()
subject.isModal = true
subject.smartBack();
var navigation = subject.navigationController as! MockNavigationController

print(subject._dismissCalled)
print(navigation._popCalled)
```

> **OUTPUT**:

```
true
false

subject = MockClassUnderTest();
subject.isModal = false
subject.smartBack();
navigation = subject.navigationController as! MockNavigationController

print(subject._dismissCalled)
print(navigation._popCalled)
```

> **OUTPUT**:

```
false
true
```

In this example, you are overriding the dismiss and pop methods which would be called in either case. In your unit test you would just assert the stubbed values (_popCalled) are true or false for your expectations.

Comment: I think the question is simply asking how to write an `if` statement that checks a condition, not how to perform a unit test.

Comment: not too sure tbh, question asks "So, how i can check if viewcontroller popped or dismissed after this function?" but yeah maybe, thanks anyway

Comment: This is a good example of mocking. It shows that the desired method was called. However, I think a better approach here is to simply check that the view controller is no longer displayed. I.e. test the effect.

Comment: Yeah there is always that option, i guess it comes down to personal preference. I have had issues previously testing this kind of effect when the presented view controller is wrapped in a navigation controller and stuff so doesn't technically return  what you'd expect on isBeingPresented and similar functions, so this is why i prefer this option myself. Would be interesting to see how someone else would test the effect in an answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way. I have needed to test a simple method that contains this: `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` and I made a temporal mock that simulates a viewController that do a push to my MainController which it is where I apply the dismissView.

```
 func testValidatesTheDismissOfViewController() {
            // Given
            let mockViewController: UIViewController = UIViewController()
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mockViewController)
// Create instance of my controller that is going to dismiss.
            let sut: HomeWireFrame = HomeWireFrame().instanceController()
            navigationController.presentFullScreen(sut, animated: true)
            // When
            sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
            sut.closeView()
            // Create an expectation...
            let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Dismiss modal view: HomeViewController")
            // ...then fulfill it asynchronously
            DispatchQueue.main.async { expectation.fulfill() }
            wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)
            // Then - if its different of my home controller
            XCTAssertTrue(!(navigationController.topViewController is HomeViewController))
          }
```

I hope can help, I´m here to any doubt.